# Unity 3D - Cenas cinematográficas (cutscenes)

Tags: unity3d, jogos

Eu estou estudando Unity3D há pouco tempo, e gostaria de saber qual o melhor modo de fazer "cenas cinematográficas" (cutscenes)... 
Por exemplo, no RPG Maker poderia criar eventos em tal posição, que acionavam-se ao chegar naquele local. A partir daí poderia se fazer movimento de personagens, câmera, falas...

O mais parecido achei com isso até agora foi esse plugin http://www.hutonggames.com/, mas queria saber se há algum modo nativo da engine.

Comment: Use os gatilhos da resposta do Guilherme abaixo, e para fazer as movimentações, caixas de diálogos, mover câmera de posição use o Animator do Unity. Explico melhor sobre ele neste vídeo.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCExJKOsSW8&list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA1RNqmaQIAWiq5HiWUGATyC Os balões de fala eu explico em outro vídeo desta mesma série.

Comment: Boa tarde, minha resposta lhe ajudou? Por favor me informe se tiver alguma duvida ainda. se não e a resposta lhe foi útil, por favor marque a como "correta". Grato.

Comment: Boa tarde, @GuilhermeNascimento. Sim, o collider e o animation sanou totalmente minha dúvida, apesar que ainda continuo estudando-os para os melhores modos de uso. Grato, e desculpe por não ter marcado antes.

Comment: Que isso, espero que participe da comunidade e que ela te ajude também com suas duvidas :) Sucesso.

Comment: Além das grandes dicas que já lhe foram dadas (e do ótimo tutorial do @Nils), se o seu jogo for focado em narrativas você pode dar uma olhada nesse add-on gratuito para a Unity3D chamado [Fungus](http://fungusgames.com/). A ferramenta facilita enormente a criação de diálogos entre personagens e o jogador, e tem uns recursos muito bacanas para fazer cutscenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sistema do RpgMaker é baseado em eventos que geralmente trabalham por colisão ou blocos do mapa. O unity3d trabalha de maneira "livre", portanto o link que você forneceu é apenas um sistema de *rpg semi-pronto*, você não precisa de "algo pronto" (a não ser que queira facilitar o trabalho), o que você precisa é estudar os eventos que já existem no Unity3d, como o Collider.

### Collider

No caso você deverá usar os eventos como:

- `OnCollisionEnter` é chamado quando um colisor/rigidbody começa a tocar outro colisor/rigidbody.
- `OnCollisionExit` é chamado quando um colisor/rigidbody parou de tocar outro rigidbody / colisor.
- `OnCollisionStay` é chamado uma vez por quadro para cada colisor/rigidbody que está tocando rigidbody / colisor.
- `OnTriggerEnter` é chamado quando o outro Collider entra no "trigger".
- `OnTriggerExit` é chamado quando o outro Collider parou de tocar o que dispara o  "trigger".
- `OnTriggerStay` é chamado um por "frame" para cada outro Collider que estiver tocando no "trigger".

Conforme o comentário do @Nils para fazer o personagem se mover de um ponto ao outro, exibir balões de falar, fazer a câmera mudar de lugar, ele vai precisar programar/configurar isso e uma boa solução é usar o `Animation` do Unity <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd/Command</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> no Mac)

Leia mais:

- [Collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)
- [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html)
- [Animation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html)

> **Nota:** trigger se refere ao objeto que dispara o evento.
>
> **Nota:** Se houver algum erro na tradução não exite em informar, grato

Comment: Complementando a resposta, o gatilhos são a primeira parte, para ele fazer o personagem se mover de um ponto ao outro, exibir balões de falar, fazer a câmera mudar de lugar, ele vai precisar programar/configurar isso. E uma boa solução é usar o `Animation` do Unity Ctrl+6 (CMd+6 no Mac)

Comment: @Nils boa dica, foi basicamente o que eu disse: *o que você precisa é estudar os eventos*. Sobre o `Animation`, pelo que li no manual do Unity3d, realmente é o que é necessário para fazer os "cutscenes" :) Obrigado pela informação.